# Seed JSON column in EF Core 7

Tags: sql, json, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I try to seed my data into my database, but I get this error:

> The seed entity for entity type 'JobState' cannot be added because it has the navigation 'FromInfo' set. To seed relationships, add the entity seed to 'JobState.FromInfo#List ' and specify the foreign key values {'JobStateId'}. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the involved property values.

My context seed:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<JobState>().HasData(
        new JobState
        {
            Id = 1,
            Active = true,
            Delete = false,
            System = true,
            JobTypeId = 1,
            CreatorId = 1,
            CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
            Form = "Init",
            FromInfo =  new List<BaseInfo>
            {
                new BaseInfo
                {
                    Title ="ثبت",
                    Description = null,
                    Language = 0
                }
            },
            To = "InProgress",
            ToInfo = new List<BaseInfo>
            {
                new BaseInfo
                {
                    Title ="در حال بررسی",
                    Description = null,
                    Language =  0
                }
            },
            IsStart = true,
            IsEnd = false,
            Roles = new List<long>
            {
                1
            },
            IsAuto = true,
            CanSelect = false,
        });
```

My context config:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<JobState>(entity => {
    entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
    entity.Property(e => e.Active).HasDefaultValueSql("((1))");
    entity.HasOne(d => d.JobType).WithMany(p => p.JobStates)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_Table_54_Table_55");
    
    entity.OwnsOne(navigationExpression: jobState => jobState.Roles, buildAction: owned => {
        owned.ToJson("Field_15");
    });
    entity.OwnsOne(navigationExpression: jobState => jobState.FromInfo, buildAction: owned => {
        owned.ToJson("Field_10");
    });
    entity.OwnsOne(navigationExpression: jobState => jobState.ToInfo, buildAction: owned => {
        owned.ToJson("Field_12");
    });
});
```

My `JobType` class:

```
[Table("Table_55")]
public class JobType : BaseEntity
{
    [Required]
    public List<BaseInfo> Info { get; set; }
    
    [InverseProperty("JobType")]
    public virtual ICollection<JobState> JobStates { get; set; } = new List<JobState>();
}
```

My `JobState` class:

```
[Table("Table_54")]
public class JobState : BaseEntity
{
    [Required]
    [Column("Field_09")]
    public string Form { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public List<BaseInfo> FromInfo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("Field_11")]
    public string To { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public List<BaseInfo> ToInfo { get; set; }

    [Column("Field_13")]
    public bool IsStart { get; set; }

    [Column("Field_14")]
    public bool IsEnd { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public List<long> Roles { get; set; }

    [Column("Field_16")]
    public bool IsAuto { get; set; }

    [Column("Field_17")]
    public bool CanSelect { get; set; }
    
    [Column("Field_18")]
    [ForeignKey("Field_18")]
    public long JobTypeId { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("JobStates")]
    public virtual JobType JobType { get; set; }
    
    [InverseProperty("State")]
    public virtual ICollection<JobHistory> JobHistories { get; set; } = new List<JobHistory>();

    [InverseProperty("JobState")]
    public virtual ICollection<Job> Jobs { get; set; } = new List<Job>();
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm, you're wanting to store JSON in a database column? Why do you want to do that? Are you aware that's an anti-pattern?

Comment: Some of My Infomation Is Dynamic Class And I Need To Store Them In Json